# Add action to NSRunAlertPanel's button

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I add action to buttons of NSRunAlertPanel. Here's how I am creating alert panel:

```
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"App Updater", 
                        @"Network Error! ....... ....", 
                        @"Ok", 
                        @"Contact Support", 
                        nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do in this case is to check the return value and then take the appropriate action:

```
NSInteger code = NSRunAlertPanel(...);
switch(code) {
  case NSAlertDefaultReturn:
  break;
  case NSAlertAlternateReturn:
  break;
  case NSAlertOtherReturn:
  break;
}
```